# Are polynomials in several variables over $\mathbb{R}$ with equal roots proportional?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

In particular if $P[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]$ and $Q[x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4]$ are homogeneous polynomials of order 2 over $\mathbb{R}$ which have the same roots, are they proportianal?

**Edit**: the question arose reading a book on special relativity in which the following argument was followed:

- space-time interval is defined in reference frame (K) as $ s[t,x,y,z] =  t^2 -  x^2 -  y^2 -  z^2$
- the coordinates of an event in a different refernce frame (K') are given by $x'^\mu = A^\mu_\nu x^\nu$ where $A^\mu_\nu$ is a matrix of real numbers to be determined ($\mu,\nu=0,1,2,3 $ and $x^0=t$, $x^1=x$, $x^2=y$, $x^3=z$)
- space-time interval in reference frame (K') is defined as $ s'[t,x,y,z] = t'^2 - x'^2 - y'^2 - z'^2 = (A^0_\nu x^\nu )^2 - (A^1_\nu x^\nu )^2 - (A^2_\nu x^\nu )^2 - (A^3_\nu x^\nu )^2$
- we require the linear transformation $A^\mu_\nu$ to be such that $ s[t,x,y,z] = 0 \iff s'[t,x,y,z] = 0$
- **hence** (the author says) $ s'[t,x,y,z] $ has to be proportional to $ s[t,x,y,z] $

I'm new to polynomial thoery therefore I thought there were a general criterion justifying the last step, but, even if it is not so, is that particular statement true?

Comment: Do you mean the same roots over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$?  For example, over $\mathbb{R}$, $ax^2+by^2$ with $a,b>0$, will have only one root, but the polynomials are, typically, not multiples.

Comment: May also depend on how you count roots; e.g. $x^2 y$ vs $x y^2$. I don't know if considering just the order 2 case avoid this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, they were useful to understand a little bit more of the subject. I edited the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3):

If they have the same roots over $ \mathbb C $ and they are irreducible, this is true by the Nullstellensatz, since both polynomials will be generators of the vanishing ideal of their mutual zero set, which means they are associates in the polynomial ring $ \mathbb C[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n] $. The only units in this ring are nonzero complex numbers, and if both $ P, Q $ have real coefficients you can show that the association holds in $ \mathbb R[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n] $ as well.

If one of these conditions fail, then there are counterexamples. For instance, for two nonconstant polynomials $ P, Q $ in the polynomial ring, $  PQ $ and $ P Q^2 $ have the same roots over $ \mathbb C $ but they are not associates. If they only have the same roots over $ \mathbb R $, then the family $ ax_1^2 + bx_2^2 $ gives many counterexamples, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Since I'm totally new to the subject I'm not sure if the particular case I'm interested in satisfies the hypothesis you wrote, therfore I edited the question to make it more specific. If you can help me to clarify that point it would be very helpful. But thank you anyway.